# Python Numpy implementing PIMC QAVRP

Tags: python, numpy, quantum-computing

I`m having some trouble implementing PIMC QAVRP, an Quantum Annealing algorithm that uses Path-Integral Monte Carlo. Actully, my problem is with numpy.

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np

#Calculo da energia potencial do sistema
def pot_energy(S, d):
    return np.sum(d * np.einsum('...i,...j,ij->...ij', S, S, np.ones_like(d)), axis=(-1, -2))

#Calculo da energia potencial do sistema
def kin_energy(S):
    Hkin = np.zeros_like(S)
    Hkin[1:] += S[:-1] * S[1:]
    Hkin[-1] += S[-1] * S[0]
    return np.sum(Hkin)

#Calculo da transformação de Suzuki-Trotter para uma replica
def suzuki_trotter_replica(S, J, dt):
    S = (S * np.exp(-1j * J * dt / 2)).astype(float)
    np.fft.fftn(S, axes=[-2, -1])
    S = (S * np.exp(-1j * J * dt / 2)).astype(float)
    np.fft.ifftn(S, axes=[-2, -1])
    S = S * np.exp(-1j * dt).astype(float)
    S[1:] *= S[:-1]
    S[-1] *= S[0]
    S = S * np.exp(-1j * dt).astype(float)
    return S

#Calculo da transformação de Suzuki-Trotter para todas as replicas
def suzuki_trotter(S, J, dt):
    for i in range(S.shape[0]):
        S[i] = suzuki_trotter_replica(S[i], J, dt)
    return S


#ALGORITIMO DE EXECUÇÃO DO QAVRP
def pimc_qa_vrp(d, num_steps, num_replicas, beta, dt):
    # Inicializa a matriz de spins aleatóriamente
    S = np.random.choice([-1, 1], size=(num_replicas, *d.shape))
    # Inicializa os arrays de energia
    H_pot = np.zeros(num_replicas)
    H_kin = np.zeros(num_replicas)
    # Loop principal
    for step in range(num_steps):
        # Aplica a transformação de Suzuki-Trotter
        S = suzuki_trotter(S, beta, dt)
        # Calcula a energia potencial do sistema
        for i in range(num_replicas):
            H_pot[i] = np.sum(pot_energy(S[i],d))
            H_kin[i] = kin_energy(S[i])
        # Calcula a energia Total
        H = H_pot / num_replicas - np.sum(H_kin) * beta / num_replicas
        # Aplica o QAVRP
        S = np.sign(np.tanh(-beta * (H - H.min()) / 2) + np.random.rand(*S[:, 0:1, :, :].shape + (1,)) - 0.5)
        '''
        Essa expressão implementa a transição quântica aleatória, onde o estado atual é atualizado para um novo estado aleatório 
        com uma probabilidade que depende da diferença de energia potencial entre os dois estados. Se a energia potencial do novo
        estado é menor do que a do estado atual, o novo estado é aceito. Caso contrário, o novo estado é aceito com uma probabilidade 
        que depende da temperatura.
        '''
    return S[0]


d = np.array([[0, 1, np.sqrt(2)],
              [1, 0, 1],
              [np.sqrt(2), 1, 0]])

num_steps = 1000
num_replicas = 100
beta = 2.0
dt = 0.1

solution = pimc_qa_vrp(d, num_steps, num_replicas, beta, dt)
print(solution)
```

When I run it, I get the following error:

```
C:\Users\vitor\OneDrive\Documentos\qiskit\test.py:16: ComplexWarning: Casting complex values to real discards the imaginary part
  S = (S * np.exp(-1j * J * dt / 2)).astype(float)
C:\Users\vitor\OneDrive\Documentos\qiskit\test.py:18: ComplexWarning: Casting complex values to real discards the imaginary part
  S = (S * np.exp(-1j * J * dt / 2)).astype(float)
C:\Users\vitor\OneDrive\Documentos\qiskit\test.py:20: ComplexWarning: Casting complex values to real discards the imaginary part
  S = S * np.exp(-1j * dt).astype(float)
C:\Users\vitor\OneDrive\Documentos\qiskit\test.py:23: ComplexWarning: Casting complex values to real discards the imaginary part
  S = S * np.exp(-1j * dt).astype(float)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\vitor\OneDrive\Documentos\qiskit\test.py", line 70, in <module>
    solution = pimc_qa_vrp(d, num_steps, num_replicas, beta, dt)
  File "C:\Users\vitor\OneDrive\Documentos\qiskit\test.py", line 51, in pimc_qa_vrp
    S = np.sign(np.tanh(-beta * (H - H.min()) / 2) + np.random.rand(*S[:, 0:1, :, :].shape + (1,)) - 0.5)
IndexError: too many indices for array: array is 3-dimensional, but 4 were indexed
```

Not really worried about the warnings, but that problem with numpy is making me crazy. I`ve tried adding new dimensions to S, but no luck at all.

I was hopping to get S[0] as the best solution for VRP!

Comment: Clearly `S[:, 0:1, :, :]` indexes 4 dimensions, right?  But what is `S`?  Your code is way too complicated for us to follow just by reading.  `S` is modified in the `step` loop, and returned 2 times, after being passed through several functions.  It's your responsibility to keep track of the dimensions of arrays.  Sometimes I have to added diagnostic `shape` prints, since it's never safe to just "assume" the shape.  Test, test, and test.

Comment: Your code indexes S, then immediately takes its shape. Are you inserting the `0:1` slice to add an axis of size 1, akin to the `(1,)` you add after? Maybe you're looking for something like: `np.random.rand(*S.shape)[:, None, :, :, None]` which would be random values like S.shape, but with an additional size 1 axis between axes 0 and 1 and at the end.

Comment: `S[:, 0:1, :, :]` could also be written as `S[:, 0:1, ...]` or even `S[:, 0:1]`.  The trailing dimensions don't have to be spelled out.  But whether that's a correct fix depends on why does this index 4 dimensions in first place.  Are there other spots in the code that depend on `S` being 4d?